# Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'mydb'

Tags: sql-server-2005

I had SQL Server 2005 on my pc and had created a few databases through it. Due to some problem, I had to reinstall it but now when i give the command "create database mydb" it says

```
"Cannot create file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\myDb.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation."
```

And when i give "use mydb" command it says

```
Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'mydb'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

What should I do so that it can locate my databases?

Comment: Do you want to use mydb if possible, rather than re-creating it?

Comment: yes. i want management studio to use mydb which is already present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-attach the database files (assuming that your current installation is at at least the same service pack/patch level as you previously had it).

You can attach the database using either [Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx), or using [`CREATE DATABASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue.

We need to use Square brackets for database name

ie

use [database]

instead of

use database

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you re-installed the instance, it won't delete any existing database files and when you are creating a new database its complaining that the file already exists in the default path.

Go to the location C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\ and manually delete the myDB.mdf and .ldf files and next go ahead with creating a new database.

HTH

Comment: But why to recreate? Aint there any way to make management studio locate the already present database?

Comment: you can (attach) do that as well but in your comments you were trying to create one and my impression was you want get a clean copy again (as in new re-install of the instance) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I simply just get this issue because I didn't change the primary available database by pressing Ctrl+U into the new DB I created. Often helps to check.